# In Webmaster tools googlebot is getting a crawl error 500 from the server

Tags: php, error-handling, googlebot

I've noticed my sites are not ranking as well as they did before and when I checked Webmaster tools I see that gooblebot cannot crawl pages that I can perfectly crawl with my browser and I'm getting an 500 error.

The websites are not WordPress and use PHP.

What can be causing this problem?

This is the actual error in WMT

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 21:04:38 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=blkss9toirna36p2mjl44htv01; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 3840
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: have you tried to do any configuration..may be with _.htaccess_..??

Comment: addtionaly check these links, if they help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521244/googlebot-crawl-error-500-and-php-error-reporting-with-a-strange-solution and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28257/why-is-google-webmaster-tools-crawling-invalid-urls-and-showing-500-errors

Answer (score 0):

You may be blocking Googlebot with .htaccess, robots.txt or by some other means (maybe firewall settings?)

a. this is not good

b. you should use WMT to get Crawl stats/Crawl Error reports and use these to get better understanding of this issue (at what URLs / How Often does this occur...)

Also, try to look at your last Google Cache date (direct search the domain and click on the Cache link in the preview window)

This may be temporary, downtime related issue that will solve itself or a site wide blocking rule that you'll need to change.

GL

Comment: I don't think I'm blocking Googlebot in the .htaccess, there is nothing there that mentions robots.

Comment: I don't think I'm blocking Googlebot in the .htaccess, there is nothing there that mentions robots.  I don't have a robots.txt file in any of the websites.  This started to happen on a specific day but I cannot find anything wrong.  I have not change anything related to the firewalls.  I'm very new at this and have no idea how else to troubleshot.  My websites are beginning to loose rank so I'm in a race against time now that I realize what the problem is.  Most of the urls that googlebot cannot access are live pages that I can access fine with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having a problem with googlebot receiving a 500 error code, I suggest you register with Google Webmaster Tools not Analytics.  If you choose Health then Fetch As Google.  You should get what the googlebot receives and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered that it was one of the plugins that was causing this. Basically I disabled every plugin and then re-enabled one, tested, re-enabled the next .......
Took about 1 hour to find the culprit but now all is good